# Hand held camera-wiggle effect on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, shake

I looking for an animation loop on flutter that will do something like that:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBCBAbR-B5w

The idea is to display a List View where every item wiggles around in a confined space.

Is there any package for that on flutter? Any guidance to do it manually if not?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try
Package https://pub.dev/packages/shake_widget
Or
Custom animation
https://codewithandrea.com/articles/shake-text-effect-flutter/